# Web API CORS FormsAuthentication from AngularJS Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I Implemented an AngularJS Project. The Server Side I coded using .NET Web API (C#). I Enabled the CORS in the Web API by installing the NuGet Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAnonymousString()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Sample AllowAnonymous", false);
        return "Calling AllowAnonymous Method using CORS - Public Text";
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAuthorizeString()
    {
        return "Calling Authorize Method using CORS - Private Text";
    }
}
```

I hosted the client Side Application in http://localhost:8050 and I hosted Service Web API in http://localhost:8060.

Now I tried to access the GetAnonymousString() - http://localhost:8060/api/Sample/GetAnonymousString its working fine and also it returns the httponly cookie to the client via response.

But I tried the same for GetAuthorizeString() - http://localhost:8060/api/Sample/GetAuthorizeString, it returns 401 Unauthorized error as a response.

If I hosted Client App and Web API in the same domain, then its working fine. Only issue is CORS.

Kindly assist me how to use the **`Authorize`** in **`CORS`** ???

Comment: How did you setup authentication in webApi?

Comment: @Legends

 `<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>`

Comment: @Legends - without CORS its working i.e., within a same domain.

Comment: So your Angular app users have to login to your web api using a login form, right?

Comment: Can we see the authentication setup of the startup.cs file in your webApi?

Comment: WebApi or WebAPI2?

Comment: @Legends Its Web API 2.2

Comment: So again, Can we see the authentication configuration setup of your webApi?

Comment: @Legends  I can't get you. Can you please...

Comment: Someting like:

` app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,`

Comment: @Legends No... I don't use as mentioned as like you...

Comment: Can you show how you register WebAPI?